# How to define a new Vim operator with a parameter?

Tags: vim

I have been looking to map a new operator in Vim that takes an extra parameter.

For example, we know that `ciw` will “cut inside word” and will put you into Insert mode. What I am looking for is having a custom action to replace `c` (for example, `s`) that takes movements like `iw`, but requires an extra parameter.

A trivial example would be:

```
Given a line in a text file
```

Execute `siw*` in Normal mode (assuming the cursor is on the first column) for it to surround the first word with `*` like so:

```
*Given* a line in a text file
```

I know, this is what the most excellent [surround.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) plugin does. But I am just giving an example here, and looking for an answer as to how to get the mappings so that the above work.

I tried playing with `onoremap` and `opfunc`, but can’t seem to get them to play the way I want.

So, what I am looking for is a combination of motions plus operator pending mappings.

Comment: Because that's what Surround does, did you look at Surround's code?

Comment: That is kind of what Surround does, except it adds the motion(s) after Vim actions like `y`, `d` and `c`. Again, note that I am giving an example, not saying I want to re-write Surround. And yes, I've seen the source for Surround.

Comment: I always think of the `c` command as _change_, not _cut_.  It allows you to _change_ text in place.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is an example implementation of the command described
in the question, for illustrative purposes.

```
nnoremap <silent> s :set opfunc=Surround<cr>g@
vnoremap <silent> s :<c-u>call Surround(visualmode(), 1)<cr>

function! Surround(vt, ...)
    let s = InputChar()
    if s =~ "\<esc>" || s =~ "\<c-c>"
        return
    endif
    let [sl, sc] = getpos(a:0 ? "'<" : "'[")[1:2]
    let [el, ec] = getpos(a:0 ? "'>" : "']")[1:2]
    if a:vt == 'line' || a:vt == 'V'
        call append(el, s)
        call append(sl-1, s)
    elseif a:vt == 'block' || a:vt == "\<c-v>"
        exe sl..','..el 's/\%'..sc..'c\|\%'..ec..'c.\zs/\=s/g|norm!``'
    else
        exe el 's/\%'..ec..'c.\zs/\=s/|norm!``'
        exe sl 's/\%'..sc..'c/\=s/|norm!``'
    endif
endfunction
```

To get user input, the function `InputChar()` is used, assuming that
the required argument is a single character.

```
function! InputChar()
    let c = getchar()
    return type(c) == type(0) ? nr2char(c) : c
endfunction
```

If it is necessary to accept a string argument, change the call to
`InputChar()` in `Surround()` to the call to `input()`, instead.

Answer (score 9):

The title of the question might cause misunderstanding.  What you want to do is to define a new operator like `y`, `d` and `c`, neither motions nor text objects, isn't it?
[`:help :map-operator`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#:map-operator) describes how to define a new operator.  To take a parameter like the surround plugin, use `getchar()` in your `'operatorfunc'`.

Though `:help :map-operator` describes the basics, it's a bit troublesome to deal with arguments passed to `'operatorfunc'`.  You can use [vim-operator-user](https://github.com/kana/vim-operator-user) to simplify the handling of arguments.  With this plugin, surround-like operator can be written as follows:

```
function! OperatorSurround(motion_wise)
  let _c = getchar()
  let c = type(_c) == type(0) ? nr2char(_c) : _c
  if c ==# "\<Esc>" || c == "\<C-c>"
    return
  endif

  let bp = getpos("'[")
  let ep = getpos("']")
  if a:motion_wise ==# 'char'
    call setpos('.', ep)
    execute "normal! \"=c\<Return>p"
    call setpos('.', bp)
    execute "normal! \"=c\<Return>P"
  elseif a:motion_wise ==# 'line'
    let indent = matchstr(getline('.'), '^\s*')
    call append(ep[1], indent . c)
    call append(bp[1] - 1, indent . c)
  elseif a:motion_wise ==# 'block'
    execute bp[1].','.ep[1].'substitute/\%'.ep[2].'c.\zs/\=c/'
    execute bp[1].','.ep[1].'substitute/\%'.bp[2].'c\zs/\=c/'
    call setpos('.', bp)
  else
  endif
endfunction
call operator#user#define('surround', 'OperatorSurround')
map s  <Plug>(operator-surround)
```

If you really want to define your own text objects, please consider [vim-textobj-user](https://github.com/kana/vim-textobj-user).

Comment: Would somebody mind giving an actual concrete example of how this work.    I've tried everything.    E.g., what command does what?   Thanks!

Comment: @LeoSimon This may be helpful. http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/32.html

Answer (score 1):

Consider one of the plugins for writing custom text objects. For example:
https://github.com/kana/vim-textobj-user