# Extract JavaScript variable (feature example): how to improve it?

Tags: vim

I am a Vim newbie with one week experience and I'm already enjoying it.

I've successfully write an (ugly) command+function+mapping with which I can extract some code to a new variable in JavaScript. This is the first version, it works with motions (\jsexviw) and selection in visual mode:

```
command! -range -nargs=1 JsExVar normal `<v`>d^[i<args>^[Ovar <args> = (^[pa);^[
function! FnJsExVar(type)
    silent exec 'JsExVar '.input("Variable name: ")
endfunction
vnoremap <silent> <expr> <Leader>jsexv ":JsExVar ".input("Variable name: ")."<cr>"
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>jsexv :set opfunc=FnJsExVar<CR>g@
```

Then I refactored it a bit to avoid duplicated input("Variable name: ") but now I have a weird (0) param when calling the function from the command:

```
command! -range JsExVar call ExecJsExVar(0) 
vnoremap <silent> <expr> <Leader>jsexv ":JsExVar<cr>"
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>jsexv :set opfunc=ExecJsExVar<CR>g@
function! ExecJsExVar(type)
    let varname = input("Variable name: ")
    silent exec "normal `<v`>di".varname."^["
    silent exec "normal Ovar ".varname." = ^["
    silent exec "normal pa;^["
endfunction
```

I still don't fully understand the different ways of executing things, so I assume the code can be improved and cleaned a lot. Thanks is advance for any correction and suggestion.

----- EDIT ------

Ok, it wasn't really working with motions. I think this works... but the question is: can this be done with one function?

```
command! -range JsExVar call JavascriptExtractVariable(0) 
vnoremap <silent> <Leader>jsxv :JsExVar<cr>
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>jsxv :set opfunc=JavascriptExtractVariable2<CR>g@
function! JavascriptExtractVariable(type)
    let varname = input("Variable name: ")
    silent exec "normal `<v`>di".varname.""
    silent exec "normal Ovar ".varname." = ("
    silent exec "normal pa);"
endfunction
function! JavascriptExtractVariable2(type)
    let varname = input("Variable name: ")
    silent exec "normal `[v`]di".varname.""
    silent exec "normal Ovar ".varname." = ("
    silent exec "normal pa);"
endfunction
```

(re-edited because wrong code)

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but Vim is a text editor, not a code editor. To manipulate code, you have to treat it like text, which is inefficient (and usually wrong, since there's no AST). Vim is designed to be inefficient, you glue small commands together which isn't inherently efficient for editing but is useful for manipulating large blocks of text. *Code* editors, like VSCode, are much better at tasks like this https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cmstead.jsrefactor

Comment: Thanks Andy, my intention is to use this example to learn more about vim, not so much about he functionality itself. I have worked with VSCode and other and now I am playing with vim to see what fits me better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994276/defining-a-new-vim-operator-with-a-parameter/8998136#8998136) I've been able to make it work without the command and with one function. And I learnt what that argument was for, how to use optional arguments and the func-range modifier:

```
vnoremap <silent> <Leader>jsxv :call JsExtractVariable(visualmode(), 1)<cr>
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>jsxv :set opfunc=JsExtractVariable<CR>g@
function! JsExtractVariable(vt, ...) range
    let varname = input("Variable name: ")
    silent exec "normal ".SelectByMode(a:0)."di".varname."^["
    silent exec "normal Ovar ".varname." = (^[pa);^["
endfunction

function! SelectByMode(isvisual)
    return (a:isvisual ? "`<v`>" : "`[v`]")
endfunction
```

I post this as an answer because it's the kind of improvement I was looking for. Any other suggestion will be welcome, thanks.