# How would I map a new operator key?

Tags: vim

I would like to map backslash as a new operator key in normal mode, so that I may then map motions to it. For example, currently I just have backslash mapped to `:%s//g<Left><Left>`, but I would like `\r` to trigger that.

I have read `:help map-operator` and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994276/defining-a-new-vim-operator-with-a-parameter), however the code given was not explained and is therefore useless to me, as I don't understand Vim scripting syntax.

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you want `\r` to produce `:%s//g<Left><Left>`, then just map it so — nothing to do with operators.

Comment: I had tried that before but it didn't work for some reason. Maybe something else I didn't notice was whack and I figured it simply wouldn't work the way I tried. Works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want something like:

```
nnoremap <Leader>r :%s//g<Left><Left>
```

Remember the default "`<Leader>`" key is "`\`" but you can change it by doing:

```
:let mapleader=","
```

Or wherever key you want